# Empty confusion matrix in Weka with test data

Tags: weka

I am classifying iris data using DECISION TREE (C4.5), RANDOM FOREST and  NAIVE BAYES. I am using the dataset downloaded from [iris-train](https://ai.arizona.edu/sites/ai/files/resources/iris-train.arff) and [iris-test](https://ai.arizona.edu/sites/ai/files/resources/iris-test.arff). When I train the all networks everything is fine with proper results with 'classifier output', 'Detailed accuracy with class' and 'confusion matrix'. But, when I select the iris-test data in the Weka-explorer-classify-test options and select the iris-test file and in 'more options' select 'output prediction' as 'csv' and click start, I am getting the result as shown in the figure below. [image: Weka output]  The  'classifier output' is showing the classified samples correctly, but, 'Detailed accuracy with class' and 'confusion matrix' is with all values zeros. Any suggestion where I am going wrong in selecting any option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion matrix shows you how well your trained classifier performs by comparing the actual class of the instances in the test set with the class that was predicted by the classifier. But you are supplying a test set with no class information, so there's nothing to compare against. This is why you see

```
Total Number of Instances         0
Ignored Class Unknown Instances   120
```

in the output in your screenshot.

Typically you would first evaluate the performance of your classifier using cross-validation, or a test set that has class information. Then you can use the trained classifier to classify unknown data, for example using the `Re-evaluate model on current test set` right-click option as [described in the help](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions).

Comment: Thank you @nekomatic, for the answer. Your explanation has solved my question, so I wish to declare "Solved" for the question.